# PyPI upload stopped working and pip install fails

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi

I submitted my first PyPI project last night and things are not working as expected (warning long post ahead)...

I originally uploaded the project, [cvrfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cvrfparse), via the commandline by doing:

```
% python setup.py sdist upload
```

This created the initial project just fine. However trying to install the project via pip, failed thusly:

```
% sudo pip install cvrfparse
Password:
Downloading/unpacking cvrfparse
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cvrfparse
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-root/cvrfparse/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from distribute_setup import use_setuptools
    ImportError: No module named distribute_setup
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-root/cvrfparse/setup.py", line 3, in <module>

    from distribute_setup import use_setuptools

ImportError: No module named distribute_setup

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-root/cvrfparse
Storing complete log in /Users/m/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

According to http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#using-setuptools-without-bundling-it it should just "work" if I have:

```
from distribute_setup import use_setuptools
use_setuptools()
```

after the loadcard in setup.py. I then tried adding distribute_setup.py to a MANIFEST.in as per:

```
% cat MANIFEST.in 
include distribute_setup.py
```

So after adding that file and bumping the version number in setup.py I then tried to upload the new package to PyPI:

```
% python setup.py sdist upload
running sdist
running egg_info
writing requirements to cvrfparse.egg-info/requires.txt
writing cvrfparse.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to cvrfparse.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to cvrfparse.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to cvrfparse.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'cvrfparse.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'cvrfparse.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
creating cvrfparse-0.10
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse.egg-info
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/sample-xml
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/common
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/common/1.1
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/cvrf
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/cvrf/1.1
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/dublincore
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/prod
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/prod/1.1
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/scap
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/vuln
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/vuln/1.1
creating cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/w3.org
making hard links in cvrfparse-0.10...
hard linking MANIFEST.in -> cvrfparse-0.10
hard linking README -> cvrfparse-0.10
hard linking distribute_setup.py -> cvrfparse-0.10
hard linking setup.py -> cvrfparse-0.10
hard linking cvrfparse/__init__.py -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse
hard linking cvrfparse/cvrfparse.py -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse
hard linking cvrfparse.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse.egg-info
hard linking cvrfparse.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse.egg-info
hard linking cvrfparse.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse.egg-info
hard linking cvrfparse.egg-info/entry_points.txt -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse.egg-info
hard linking cvrfparse.egg-info/requires.txt -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse.egg-info
hard linking cvrfparse.egg-info/top_level.txt -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse.egg-info
hard linking cvrfparse/sample-xml/CVRF-1.1-cisco-sa-20110525-rvs4000.xml -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/sample-xml
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/catalog.xml -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/common/1.1/common.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/common/1.1
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/cvrf/1.1/cvrf.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/cvrf/1.1
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/dublincore/dc.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/dublincore
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/prod/1.1/prod.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/prod/1.1
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/scap/cpe-language_2.2a.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/scap
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/scap/cvss-v2_0.9.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/scap
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/scap/scap-core_0.9.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/scap
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/vuln/1.1/vuln.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/vuln/1.1
hard linking cvrfparse/schemata/w3.org/xml.xsd -> cvrfparse-0.10/cvrfparse/schemata/w3.org
Writing cvrfparse-0.10/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'cvrfparse-0.10' (and everything under it)
running upload
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    ['cvrfparse = cvrfparse.cvrfparse:main',]}
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/upload.py", line 60, in run
    self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/upload.py", line 135, in upload_file
    self.password)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

It appears as though something is `None` where it was previously some?

I then tried to upload the package manually by creating a distribution via:

```
% python setup.py sdist
```

And uploading that file to PyPI via the web interface. pip install still reports the same problem with this new .10 package. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Either username or password is `None` for that line. Check your `.pypirc` file in your home directory.

Comment: username is correct, password is omitted. According to http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/packageindex#the-pypirc-file if the password field is omitted, the user will be prompted to enter it. I tried adding an empty password "`password:`" and then I got a 401 error from the server "`Upload failed (401): Unauthorized`". Problem still unresolved.

Comment: More info: I reran `$ python setup.py register` and was re-prompted for login/password information which I opted to save to ~/.pypirc. Next, I did `$ python setup.py sdist upload` which gave yet another error message: `Upload failed (400): Bad Request`.

Comment: It looks like this is still an ongoing problem. Without password field in .pypirc it fails with `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`. With the password field, but blank, I get `Upload failed (401): Incorrect password`. With the password in .pypirc, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyPI seems to have your package and loads it just fine (for me, on Ubuntu 12.04.2 in a clean virtualenv). Your tool uses console_scripts and your main requires an argument (progname), which load_enry_point() (setuptools) doesn't send. Just assign a default value to that parameter. Eg:

```
def main(progname=sys.argv[0]):
```

and you should be golden. Don't forget to update your version number and repush to PyPI.

Comment: Thanks William. Both `python setup.py sdist upload` and `pip install cvrfparse` are working as expected. I fixed the bug you mentioned and all is well.